# Loglogistic distribution r

Tags: r

There are some packages in R which produce numbers coming from a loglogistic distribution.
One example is the package FAdist. In particular I am trying to use the function rllog to obtain numbers coming from a loglogistic distribution, but it's not clear to my how are the parameters defined.

What is the full version of the pdf of a number produced when using the rllog function for shape parameter a and scale parameter b?

Comment: Apparently your question is more about the form of the PDF of a loglogistic rather than how to implement it in R. It'd be more appropriate in Cross Validated.

Comment: But I know the PDF of a loglogistic in general, but I don't know which formation is used in R. I am interested in what type of formula is used by R in order to obtain numbers from loglogistic.

Comment: What function are you trying to use to generate those numbers? Have you tried checking its help page?

Comment: I am trying to use the rllog function, however its help page is not helpfull.